# Nesting groups with apiblueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

Hi I am trying to nest groups using api blueprint documentation does anyone know if there is a way that this is possible?

I tried

```
# group test

## group inner test
```

and had no success.

Comment: It should be totally possible. WOuld you mind elaborate the question please?

Comment: I actually ended up talking to the developers on their help chat and was told that it is not possible. I was wanting to have say a group called pizzas and then inside thst group you gave the group meat pizzas and the group vegetarian pizzas. So the two smaller groups would be within the larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `# Group foo` only seems to work on the first level and there are no sub groups:

https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#resource-group-section